# Additional website in IIS 6

Tags: iis, web-applications, iis-6

Rather new to administering IIS.

we have a windows 2003 server running IIS 6 (no ssl). One of the applications a user built is for droid phones and they require an SSL connection exclusively. the customer bought an ssl cert and wants every user calling the website to be forced to use a SSL connection.

Question: Would I have to create a copy site of Default web site, and apply this SSL and set it so that only port 443 can access this?

or, is there an easier way to go about this?

I was told that applying the SSL cert to the existing defualt website won't work because if you do that, and forced all connections to port 443, the internal users will fail.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I needed to run multiple sites on IIS I usually just created additional subweb underneath Default Web Site - it was working quite well, and you should be able to set up ssl just for it I believe.

on IIS7 (not sure if that will be possible with IIS6) as well I often create multiple top level sites, and map them to different FQDNs. You can also map those to different ports using the same FQDN, but that obviously is less than ideal.

Comment: OK - I'll look into adding a sub-website. Thanks.